# CMA-ES parameter optimization Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm new to Python and I want to apply the CMA-ES function for parameter optimization. I was using the CMA_ES package in R where the implementation for this example is simple and clear. Now the implementation in Python is not so clear for me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

itr=np.array([ 803.3333,788.3333,779.5000,765.8333,753.3333,735.8333, 
717.6666,704.6666,691.6666])
Tcell=np.array([39.5333,38.5499, 37.7999,37.5999, 
38.3333,37.4166,37.4166,37.3833,36.5666])

 #### THE MODEL######
 def pvwatts2(Pdc0,gammapdc,Tref):
 return itr/1000*Pdc0*(1+gammapdc*(Tcell-Tref))

 r=(pvwatts2(75,-0.005,25))

 ####THE ORIGINAL DATA########
 P=np.array([55.7666,54.6817,54.2812,
53.6679,52.6567,51.4856,50.4057,49.3098,48.8929])

 #####RMSE#########
  def RMSE(gammapdc):
      return np.sqrt(((pvwatts2(75,gammapdc,25)-P)**2).mean())

  print(RMSE(-0.005))# This is the value of RMSE 0.253590052077
```

Now I want to minimize the RMSE with the help of CMAES in Python. I know that the ideal value of the gammapdc should be around -0.005, where the RMSE have the smallest value.

```
  ########################### MINIMIZING THE RMSE WITH CMA_ES########
   import cma
   help(cma.fmin)
```

For me it is not clear how to use the function to get the value of gamapdc to minimize the RMSE. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Is there any reproducible example that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMA_ES optimization in Python doesn't support one dimensional optimization. So the solution is to add one additional parameter

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Covariance Matrix Adaptation if you want to optimize a 1D function, so CMA-ES might not be what you are looking for. Still CMA-ES provides Step Size Adaptation which may be interesting even for 1D, and this is really simple so you can implement it yourself if you want, check the litterature about One Fifth Success Rule to start.

I suggest you start with `scipy.optimize` API : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html and look at the first section **Scalar Functions Optimization**. There is a bunch of methods more appropriate for your problem.